Issue with VP8 video transparency in Unity for Android
I'm using Unity to create an application that displays video from a URL. The video is in webm format with the VP8 codec. In the Unity editor, everything works as expected - the video is displayed with a transparent background. However, when building the project for Android, the transparency is lost, and the video is displayed with an opaque background.
I don't use shaders, but I tried it didn't help either

Here's a snippet of my code:
[SerializeField] private RawImage _rawImage;
[SerializeField] private UnityEngine.Video.VideoPlayer _videoPlayer;

private void Start()
{
    string pathToSaveVideo;

    if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android)
    {
        pathToSaveVideo = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "12.webm");
    }
    else if (Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer)
    {
        pathToSaveVideo = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "12.webm");
    }
    else
    {
        pathToSaveVideo = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "12.webm");
    }
    _videoPlayer.url = pathToSaveVideo;
    _videoPlayer.Prepare();
    _videoPlayer.prepareCompleted += (videoPlayer) =>
    {
        _videoPlayer.Play();
    };
}


Please refer to the following forum post:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/transcode-vp8-video-with-transparency-at-runtime-on-android.732131/

Sorry but it didn't help (
